# MACOS Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I tried to install `mysql-python`
by using:

```
pip3 install mysql-python
```

> Collecting mysql-python   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/private/var/folders/lw/4nw2sv5d4_n59wp2j79gn8gr0000gn/T/pip-install-e27w2zbw/mysql-python/setup.py",
>   line 13, in 
>           from setup_posix import get_config
>         File "/private/var/folders/lw/4nw2sv5d4_n59wp2j79gn8gr0000gn/T/pip-install-e27w2zbw/mysql-python/setup_posix.py",
>   line 2, in 
>           from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
>
> ```
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> ```
>
> /private/var/folders/lw/4nw2sv5d4_n59wp2j79gn8gr0000gn/T/pip-install-e27w2zbw/mysql-python/

or

```
pip install mysql-python
```

> EPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
>   2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
>   2.7. Collecting mysql-python   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/private/var/folders/lw/4nw2sv5d4_n59wp2j79gn8gr0000gn/T/pip-install-YPYuVV/mysql-python/setup.py",
>   line 17, in 
>           metadata, options = get_config()
>         File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
>           libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
>         File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
>           if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
>       IndexError: string index out of range
>
> ```
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> ```
>
> /private/var/folders/lw/4nw2sv5d4_n59wp2j79gn8gr0000gn/T/pip-install-YPYuVV/mysql-python/

I tried some solutions:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
>   2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
>   2.7. Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (40.8.0)

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

> Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>   (40.8.0)

but they dont work.