# Django project requirements.txt installation ERROR

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, psycopg2

SPECS

- macOS 10.12.6
- Python virtual environment
- [GitHub project](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/digital-marketplace)

COMMAND

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

ERROR

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/var/folders/rk/cd2m2z5s3cdfx12h9ltqk3500000gn/T/pip-install-e01ltqev/psycopg2/
```

TRIED SOLUTIONS

- https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/comments/13241

  - [install Psycopg2 on mac osx 10.9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866695/install-psycopg2-on-mac-osx-10-9-5) this answer has the same answer `brew install postgres` what did not solved my question and I have listed it previously here https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/comments/13241
- ["python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068325/python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)
- [MACOS Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487585/macos-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1?noredirect=1)
- https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server/issues/370

Comment: Try pip3? Or update python maybe.

Comment: tha is not working

Comment: After you have installed `postgres` with Homebrew, post the _complete_ log of the `pip install psycopg2` command.

Comment: `brew install postgresql@9.6 && export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin:$PATH" && pip install psycopg2`